# Parsing Bison/YACC .y files without parsing all of the C language

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I would like to parse the grammar definition from a Bison/YACC `.y` file. The syntax of the rules is very simple (and I can ignore everything outside the grammar rules section), and I don't need information about the semantic actions. However, even to skip the actions seems to require parsing the arbitrary C code fragments to determine where the `{...}` block ends (since you can have nested blocks etc.).

Is there a shortcut to this that doesn't require parsing C?

I guess one workaround would be to ask Bison itself to strip out all callbacks and just leave the grammar rules in the file which would then be trivial to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `bison` with the `-v` flag, it will produce a file called `basename.output` which starts with the grammar (without actions). It's pretty easy to parse that report. (`basename` is the name of the input file, or of the output file if you specify the `--output` option, with the extension stripped off.)

The only other way to do it is to be prepared to duplicate most of bison's parsing, which involves at least *lexing* C, if not fully parsing it, as well as understanding how to parse all of bison's `%` commands.

**Note**: The grammar produced by the `-v` option has mid-rule actions transformed into non-terminals with empty right-hand-sides. The generated non-terminals have names of the form `$@<number>` or `@<number>`, so they're easy to identify.

Comment: Agreed, one might have to parse the essential bison syntax.  But to skip over the embedded C stuff, you don't actually need to lex all of C C; it only requires lexing C text to the point of reliably counting/matching nested {...}, which means pretty much ignoring braces inside literal strings and maybe inside #define macro bodies to the extent that bison allows them.

Answer (score 2):

Recognizing and skipping over C code with braces is pretty trivial in flex:

```
%x cblk cstr cchr ccom cppcom
%%
                       int brace_depth;
{                      brace_depth=0; BEGIN(cblk);
<cblk>{                brace_depth++;
<cblk>}                if (!brace_depth--) BEGIN(INITIAL);
<cblk>\"               BEGIN(cstr);
<cblk>\'               BEGIN(cchr);
<cblk>\/\*             BEGIN(ccom);
<cblk>\/\/             BEGIN(ccpcom);
<cstr,cchr>\\.         ;
<cstr>\"               BEGIN(cblk);
<cchr>\'               BEGIN(cblk);
<ccom>\*\/             BEGIN(cblk);
<cppcom>\n             BEGIN(cblk);
<cblk,cchr,cstr,ccom,cppcom>.|\n   ;
```

Comment: Does this account for escaped " inside a quoted string?  Other crucial escapes?  If not, should be pretty easy to fix.

Comment: @IraBaxter It handles escapes (`\\.`) but not comments. Still, easy enough to fix that too.

Comment: @rici: yes, comments are trivial to add.  IraBaxter: What other crucial escapes?  As written, this allows newlines in strings (which are not allowed by the C spec and cause undefined behavior), but any valid C/C++ should be fine.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: in flex regexen, / is an operator